# Django admin: group two fields in a section without having to specify every other field as well?

Tags: django, django-admin

I have a Django model with a whole bunch of fields. In the Admin UI I want to group two of these fields in their own little section, but as far as I know that means I now have to specify every single model field in the `fieldsets` config:

```py
@admin.register(MyModel)
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fieldsets = (
        (
            None,
            {
                "fields": ("field_1", "field_2", "field_3") # etc etc
            }
        ),
        (
            "My special section",
            {
                "fields": ("field_11", "field_12")
            }
        )
    )
```

It's annoying to copy and paste so many field names, but worse: if I add a new field to the model I have to remember to add it to the `fieldsets` config as well.

So my question is: is there no way to have some kind of "the rest of the fields go here" section? Or another way to only change the section of a subset of fields while leaving the rest alone?